# An interview puzzle

Tags: java, algorithm

Write Java code to find a 9 letter string of characters that contains only letters from: 
    acegikmnoprstuvy

where hashing the string produces: 
    932246728227799

If the hash function is defined by the following pseudo-code:

```
hash (String s) { 
    h = 7 
    letters = "acegikmnoprstuvy" 
    for(i = 0; i < s.length; i++) { 
        h = (h * 37 + letters.indexOf(s[i])) 
    } 
    return h 
}
```

For example, if we were trying to find the 7 letter string where hashing the string produced 690336378753, the answer would be "reports".

Comment: So ... what more clues do you need?

Comment: if you are willing to help, feel free. no hate please. i am only trying to learn

Comment: Just brute force it - even with repeated letters, there are only ~11k possible combinations of a 9 letter string from your list of letters.

Comment: Here's a clue. Write the number in base `37`. `37` was presumably chosen because `Character.MAX_RADIX` is `36`.

Comment: BudsNankis: help with what?

Comment: I donot want to brute force it.

Comment: See, not wanting to brute force it is precisely the sort of thing that you could mention in your original question to explain to people reading it exactly *what sort of help* you are looking for.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Yeah, after remembering how to math (it's been a long day), your base `37` trick was spot on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash essentially encodes the string from base 37 to base 10. To reverse the hash, we convert from base 10 to base 37. Might as well look up the characters while we're at it.

```
public class Hashcode {
  static final String ALPHABET = "acegikmnoprstuvy";

  public static long hash(String s) {
    long h = 7;
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
      h = (h * 37 + ALPHABET.indexOf(s.charAt(i)));
    }
    return h;
  }

  public static String unhash(long n) {
    String result = "";
    while (n>7) {
      result = ALPHABET.charAt((int)(n%37)) + result;
      n = n/37;
    }
    if (n != 7) {
      System.err.println("Error, hash parity incorrect.");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(hash("reports"));
    System.out.println(unhash(690336378753L));
    System.out.println(unhash(932246728227799L));
    System.out.println(hash("mymitsapp"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why you think this answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

Look at what the function does mathematically.

You start with h = 7 when you enter the for loop. The for loop is looping through the letters in the word. Each iteration updates h: `h = h * 37 + next_letter`

So try picking a word, ex "ADD".
Loop 1: `h = 7 * 37 + "A"`
Loop 2: `h = (7 * 37 + "A") * 37 + "D"` → `7 * 37^2 + "A" * 37 + "D"`
Loop 3: `h = (7 * 37^2 + "A" * 37 + "D") * 37 + D` → `7 * 37^3 + "A" * 37^2 + "D" * 37 + "D"`

So your hash will be `7 * 37^3 + "A" * 37^2 + "D" * 37 + "D"`

In the actual case the letters are converted into index numbers, and because the max index is less than 37 you will only get one possible solution. Rewriting the hash as `7 * 37^3 + "A" * 37^2 + "D" * 37 + "D"` also shows how clearly it can be written in base 37 as `7 "A" "D" "D"`.

Long answer short: Just convert it into base 37 and remove the leading 7.

Comment: Should give credit to pbabcdefp, I was going to solve numerically without switching bases. Base 37 makes it visually obvious.

Answer (score 1):

so basically, youll wind up solving this:
    `word(hashcode,len) = let w: hash(w) = hashcode`
or to have a more specific function:

```
word(hashcode,len) = let w: for(i = 0 , i < len , 1){w[len-i-1] * 37^i} + 909732178565539 - hashcode = 0
```

So now we've got an equation, next step is solving it: 
convert `(hashcode-909732178565539)` from decimal to base 37. In a number with base 37, every digit will represent one char from your word. Now all you need to do is convert the single digits into your chars.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution written in php. All you need to do is unhash in base 37 the integer given.

```
function unhash($h) {  
    $letters = "acegikmnoprstuvy";
    //new string return 
    $s='';
    while ($h>7){
        //hold
        $pos = fmod($h, 37);
        $s = $letters[$pos].$s;
        $h = ($h-$pos) / 37 ;
    }
    return $s;
}
```